# Java Bluejay ')' expected error seems inaccurate

Tags: java, parentheses

This is my code so far:

```
public class PersonTester
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  DataSet personData = new DataSet(Measurer measureMore); 
  //error at Measurer "')' expected"

  data.add(new Person("Joe", 183));
  data.add(new Person("Chrissy", 158));
  data.add(new Person("Bobby", 175));

  double avg = data.getAverage();
  Person max = (Person) data.getMaximum();

  System.out.println("Average height: " + avg);
  System.out.println("Expected: 172.0");
  System.out.println("Name of tallest person: " + max.getName());
  System.out.println("Expected: Joe");
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell there should not be a missing parenthesis because the interface needs the variable, and I copy and pasted it from the class constructor itself which did compile properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to declare or initialize a variable and pass in one step.

Try one of these options:

```
DataSet personData = new DataSet(new Measurer());
```

or if you need a reference to the `Measure` instance:

```
Measurer measureMore = new Measurer();
DataSet personData = new DataSet(measureMore);
```

Comment: Thank you! Measurer was the interface, but I created a reference to the class that implemented it and then called it in the parameter and it worked

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a variable `measureMore` in a method call you don't put the type. You need to create the Measurer object first and then pass it to the constructor like:

```
DataSet personData = new DataSet(measureMore);
```

At least that's a start!

Answer (score 0):

`DataSet` is an interface like you said, but you cannot instantiate an interface (can't use `new`). In order to use this, you would need to instead find or create a class that implements `DataSet` and then instantiate that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler goes on parsing as long as the code it has processed is the start of some valid program. If it gets to a point at which there is no valid continuation, it reports as "expected" one of the tokens that would have let it continue parsing.

In this case,

```
public class PersonTester
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  DataSet personData = new DataSet(
```

could have been valid. `new DataSet` would have had to be the start of an anonymous inner class declaration that implements DataSet, in which case the next token would have been ")", followed by the "{" opening the body of the class declaration.

As well as explaining the error message, this suggests an additional way of changing the code to be valid - use an anonymous inner class as the initializer.